# import excel sheet with multiple value in c#

Tags: c#

I want to export the excel sheet but lblvess is contain multiplce value show it is not export the excel sheet.it can print only single value how can show all value of lblvess.where  ws.Cell("A5").Value = lblvess is export only single value

Code:-

```
for (int j = 0; j < gvvessel.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
       Label lblvess =(Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblvesselName");
       ws.Cell("A5").Value = lblvess;

        }
```

Comment: You want that value add to a5 then a6.. ?

Comment: Yes a5 to a6-----an

Comment: what is `gvvessel`?

Comment: do you want to copy `gvvessel` datagrid values into an excel file or what?

Comment: yes i want to copy gvvessel gridview values into an excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < gvvessel.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    int index=5;
    Label lblvess =(Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblvesselName");
    ws.Cell("A"+index.ToString()).Value = lblvess.Text;
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Hi sir it can show this after apply your solution "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label".  it does not show all values

Comment: gvvessel is my Gridview ID

Comment: the excel sheet contain multiple gridview value so there is problems after copy first gridview then second gridview.kindly sir help

Comment: Label lblvess = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblvesselName");
            string mylblvess = lblvess.Text;
            ws.Cell("A" + index.ToString()).Value = mylblvess;
            index++;

Comment: this is solution and it working fine

Comment: Yes.I haven't paid attention. I updated my answer. Please, mark the answer as accepted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: hi sir kindly suggest me how can set width of this cells

Comment: hi. you can use ws.Columns("A").Width = 7;